# AWS Lambda service can't access target group when VPC is enabled

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, lambda

I have a target group which has two EC2 instances behind an application load balancer. I'm trying to build a lambda service to monitor EC2 instance healthy status outside of load balancer listener.
this lambda works as expected if VPC is not enabled. once I enabled VPC, then following code will fail:

```
client = boto3.client("elbv2", region_name=default_region_name)
tg_res = client.describe_target_groups(Names=[self.name])
```

API describe_target_groups will stuck there until timeout.

this VPC does have internet access and security group inbound/outbound temporary open for all IP.

any hit will be highly appreciated.

==========update==================
From lambda log, timeout happens at:

```
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): elasticloadbalancing.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
```

I checked network setting and I'm sure this VPC has NAT configuration.

Comment: Refer to this link: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-access-resources-in-a-vpc-from-your-lambda-functions/

Comment: Could you please provide more details about the configuration -- Are you linking the Lambda function to a Public or a Private subnet? If Private, is there a NAT Gateway or NAT Instance giving access to the Internet? What is the configuration of the Security Group on the Load Balancer?

Answer (score 1):

this issue is solved by assigned another two internal access only subnets. 
1) two EC2 instances are behind an ALB. EC2 instances are in subnet, let's say: west-2a-public, west-2b-public. These two subnets are internet facing and can assign public IP.
2) I assigned lambda service into same subnet: west-2a-public and west-2b-public but it doesn't work.
3) I then assigned lambda service into another two subnets: west-2a-private and west-2b-private. These two subnet does have NAT but doesn't have public IP assignment.

I guess the issue the router mapping but I need time to figure out exactly root cause. so far, it works.

Comment: Solved my issue. Thanks! Do you know the root cause during the time?

Comment: Ops, totally forgot this since I’m mainly on Azure now. Glad it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to edit your aws lambda function to add VPC support.
You can read more about [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason for this is the following: First, you need a NAT Gateway to access the Internet for Lambda functions as described here:
https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/aws/new-access-resources-in-a-vpc-from-your-lambda-functions/

> Internet Access – As soon as you enable this functionality for a
>   particular function, the function no longer has access to the Internet
>   by default. If your function requires this type of access, you will
>   need to set up a Managed NAT Gateway in your VPC (see New – Managed
>   NAT (Network Address Translation) Gateway for AWS for more
>   information) or run your own NAT (see NAT Instances).

Second, if you have an EC2 instance or other Service such as a Load Balancer that need to be accessible inbound from the internet then you also need an Internet Gateway. **However, it is not possible to assign an Internet Gateway and the NAT to one subnet.** Therefore, you need to setup two subnets.

Here is an article describing the correct setup and configurations:
https://marcelog.github.io/articles/aws_lambda_internet_vpc.html